# SUBMERGE - transitive or intransitive

Tags: verbs

Usually, SUBMERGE is transitive.

**She's a marvelous actress who submerges herself totally in her roles.**

But there is an example in a dictionary which (the example) takes the intransitive SUBMERGE

**We watched as the divers prepared to submerge.**

After reading the sentence, I started thinking what if there were something added to the sentence.

**We watched as the divers prepared to submerge into the sea.**

Would it be correct? If it's correct then this would be also correct:

**She's a marvelous actress who submerges totally in her roles.**

In other words, why is "themselves" missing in **We watched as the divers prepared to submerge.**

Comment: Like many if not most action verbs, _submerge_ can be used either intransitively (_It submerged silently_) or transitively, in which case it's causative, meaning "cause to submerge". _We have never submerged the whole vehicle before_.

Comment: It's clear that it can be used either way. The problem was to figure out when it should be used one way or the other.

Comment: Either use can occur with locational phrases, and often does. But they're not required.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that the word is *usually* transitive - as your first two examples show, it depends on context. One context uses it transitively, the other intransitively. This isn't unusual - lots of verbs are like that. For example, you can walk, but you can also walk the dog.

You asked if this was correct:

> We watched as the divers prepared to submerge into the sea.

It's not incorrect grammatically, it's just pointless and sounds weird for a few reasons. Firstly, 'submerge' specifically means *to descend into water*, so "into the sea" is not needed. It would be especially unnecessary (and possibly misleading) if the divers were already *in* the sea, on the surface, preparing to submerge. Also, to be clear - even if you did say this, it isn't using the verb transitively. The sea isn't the object, just the place they are going - like saying "I walked in the park" (the park isn't walking, and the sea isn't submerging).

Nothing is missing from "*we watched as the divers prepared to submerge*". The verb is being used correctly, without an object. It is tacitly understood that the divers are submerging themselves, as opposed to submerging someone or something else (eg "I submerged my rubber ducky in the bathwater").

The other context you asked about, involving an actor, is of course metaphorical. They aren't actually going into water. Saying an actor was "submerged in the role" could sound like the role involved them being put underwater! Or you they could have been metaphorically 'plunged' into it by someone else, such as their director. Sometimes it is important to use the verb transitively to make it clear who *is* submerging, and who is causing it, even if it is yourself.

Comment: OK. If I want to say "I'd like to submerge into an English speaking environment", will I need to say "submerge myself" or just "submerge"?

Comment: @user1425 In the metaphorical sense, it just makes it clearer when you indicate that the person submerging is causing it themselves. I've tweaked my final paragraph, hopefully its clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at two different definitions of "submerge". The first literal one, meaning to descend below the surface of a liquid, can be transitive or intransitive, as you've demonstrated.

The other definition, the figurative one, means roughly to engross yourself in something. This definition can only be used transitively, so your sentence about the marvellous actress is wrong.

That said, it doesn't sound awful, so there's definitely room for it to be used intransitively *in a poetic way*, but that's not the same thing as it being correct.